# Retrive text from formsfx field

Tags: javafx

i was using formsfx to play around, and in some ways it really is awesome, but i have stumbled upon a problem i dont know to solve or how.

```
Form formInstance = Form.of(
              Group.of(
                      Field.ofStringType(u.nameProperty())
                              .label("name")
                              .placeholder("ha")
                              .required("must not be empty")

                              .validate(StringLengthValidator.atLeast(2, "must be at least 2 chars long")),
                      Field.ofStringType(u.lastNameProperty())
                              .label("lastname")
                              .placeholder("enter last name")
                              .required("must not be empty")
                              .tooltip("bla bla")
                              .validate(StringLengthValidator.exactly(2, "must be longer then 2 chars"))

              ));
```

When i map my DAO with this form, it does work, i can both map read data to those fields or use fields to persist new user, now i would like to do this, but without DAO.

example :

```
Form formInstance = Form.of(
              Group.of(
                      Field.ofStringType("HOW TO GET THIS")
                              .label("name")
                              .placeholder("ha")
                              .required("must not be empty")

                              .validate(StringLengthValidator.atLeast(2, "must be at least 2 chars long")),
                      Field.ofStringType("HOW TO GET THIS")
                              .label("lastname")
                              .placeholder("enter last name")
                              .required("must not be empty")
                              .tooltip("bla bla")
                              .validate(StringLengthValidator.exactly(2, "must be longer then 2 chars"))

              ));
```

I tryed to do this

```
SimpleTextControl tx = new SimpleTextControl();
 Field.ofStringType(u.lastNameProperty())
                          .label("lastname")
                          .placeholder("enter last name")
                          .required("must not be empty")
                          .tooltip("bla bla")
                          .validate(StringLengthValidator.exactly(2, "must be longer then 2 chars"))
                          .render(tx)
```

but still i cant call any method to tx, that would retrive text from the controll.

Does this means that formsfx can only be used with underlaying DAO  ?

i did look through demo, and all that was done is demo was done with the existing DAO, but there was no passing of random text or input.

[formsfx](https://github.com/dlemmermann/formsfx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this, because it cant be done, formsfx fields are bound to the property field of dao.